# Error 'tesseract/baseapi.h' file not found when building opencv from source on macos

Tags: macos, opencv

I am building `opencv 4.1.0` from source on `mojave` and it gets to 54% before dying with the stated error:

```
/git/opencv-4.1.0/opencv_contrib/modules/text/src/precomp.hpp:54:10:
  fatal error: 'tesseract/baseapi.h' file not found
```

There is a github issue for this at https://github.com/otiai10/gosseract/issues/40 : and I have applied two of the recommended patches:

> on osx, this is solved using homebrew: brew install tesseract

The notes on that in any case are from 2015 and did not have any effect. Pointers on getting through this particular error on the journey to building  `opencv` on macos would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing my googling query a bit the last suggestion here does work - https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs/issues/179 - to manually add the header include to the *CPATH*:

```
in my case cpp command was not aware of tesseract headers.
You can see cpp-includes with command cpp -v.

Solution for me was to make tesseract-includes availble by defining export CPATH="/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.0.0_1/include" and then run the build command.
```

This can be applied to the `make` command:

```
  CPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.0.0_1/include make -j4
```

Answer (score 1):

@javadba, thank you for your solution.

---

**For OSX macOS user (Mojave)**, maybe it will help yours.
OpenCV with Java Support
[OpenCV OSX Guide](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/17/install-opencv-4-on-macos/)

Additional I made JAVA Support here:
And Launch make with custom TESSERACT path

```
 cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
-D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=`python -c 'import subprocess ; import sys ; s = subprocess.check_output("python-config --configdir", shell=True).decode("utf-8").strip() ; (M, m) = sys.version_info[:2] ; print("{}/libpython{}.{}.dylib".format(s, M, m))'` \
-D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=`python -c 'import distutils.sysconfig as s; print(s.get_python_inc())'` \
-D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python \
-D BUILD_LIBPROTOBUF_FROM_SOURCES=ON \
-D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
-D BUILD_opencv_java=ON \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..

 CPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.1.0/include make
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you changed specifically for java support?  Also in what file did you make the change for the updated `cmake` shown in your answer?

Comment: Hey brother, 
-D BUILD_opencv_java=ON \

Comment: Thx: suggest you copy/add that comment to your answer as well since not everyone  checks comments (though I do ;) )